# Prove this is a tautology with logical equivalence laws only.

Tags: logic

$[(p \lor q) \land (\lnot p \lor r)] \to (q \lor r)$ is a tautology
I'm not sure how to prove this is a tautology.
Tried using $(p \to q)\equiv (\lnot p \lor q)$.

Comment: If you can use truth tables, that would be one way to show the tautology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using that equivalence $A\to B\equiv \neg A \lor B$, and the fact(s) that $\land, \lor$ are commutative, the hypothesis is equivalent to
$$
(\neg r \to \neg p) \land (\neg p \to q),\tag{Hyp.}
$$
(For example, ($\neg r \to \neg p) \equiv (\neg p \lor r)$.) This is the premise of a syllogism. From (Hyp.), you can infer $\neg r \to q$, or equivalently, after eliminating double negation and using commutativity or $\lor$,
$$
q \lor r. \tag{*}
$$
(Every instance of $[(A\to B)\land(B\to C)]\to (A\to C)$ is a tautology, a theorem, is valid; so from that together with (Hyp.), (*) follows  by Modus Ponens.)

This shows that 
$$
(p \lor q) \land (\neg p \lor r) \vdash (q \lor r),
$$
so the result follows from the Deduction Theorem.

Comment: Who downvoted this?? I'll upvote to help cancel it, and also since it looks like it used exactly what OP had included as what he/she was trying to use.

Comment: @coffeemath Thanks :) I meant to ask the same thing myself. Insane downvotes with no reason given are always a pleasure, right?

Answer (score 0):

If we use $\models (p \lor q) \land (\lnot p \lor r) \rightarrow (q \lor r)$ to denote that the given proposition is a tautology we may use the deduction theorem. This theorem says that $\models p \rightarrow q \iff p \models q$, in words p implies q is a tautology if and only if p being true forces q to be true. Applying this to the problem you have, we get $\models (p \lor q) \land (\lnot p \lor r) \rightarrow (q \lor r) \iff (p \lor q) \land (\lnot p \lor r) \models (q \lor r)$. Now, in order for $(p \lor q) \land (\lnot p \lor r)$ to be true, we need both $(p \lor q)$ and $(\lnot p \lor r)$ to be true. Now we have two cases, when p is true and when p is not true. Suppose p is true. Then it must be the case that r is true in order for $(\lnot p \lor r)$ to be true. But now $(q \lor r)$ must be true. Now suppose that p is not true. Now we must have that q is true and that r can be either true or false. Either way $(q \lor r)$ is true. Thus, $(p \lor q) \land (\lnot p \lor r) \rightarrow (q \lor r)$ is a tautology by the deduction theorem.

Comment: Some users are on a downvote rampage...